# How do i set a default keypair for an openstack user?

Tags: jenkins, openstack, jclouds

How can I set a default keypair for a user in openstack?

I'm using jenkins with the jclouds plugin, which doesn't support keypair selection. The jclouds documentation says:

```
injection of an SSH key from the JClouds is not working (but working for the registered user's default key)
```

I cannot find anything in the openstack documentation about setting a default keypair for a user.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no such thing as a default keypair for a user in OpenStack.

However, the [jclouds Jenkins Plugin doc](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JClouds+Plugin) reads

> Fill in the configuration options
>   ...
>   RSA Private Key/Public Key: If you have a keypair, then just copy paste the public and private key parts, otherwise click on `Generate Key Pair` button.

Seems like that might work for you.

Comment: We've stored a default user on our corp cloud. But I'll do some experimenting with this on monday and let you know. Thanks for the answer!